# Next.js - Is there a way to get environment variables from AWS S3 when running Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js

I previously saved the env file in the local environment and loaded it from next.config.js and used it.

The env file contains the server api address or secret key.

I am trying to upload the env content to AWS S3, and import it the first time I run next.js.

Is there any way?

In the django environment, I found a possible way.

However, I couldn't find it in Next.js

Comment: S3 does not have environment variables. Can you clarify what do you mean?

Comment: @Marcin I mean putting an environment variable file(.env or other randomly created file) in AWS S3 to get the environment variable when next.js is run on the server.

Comment: And I looked for a service called `Amazon Secrets Manager`, but I still couldn't find a way to load it on initial startup in Next.js.